Content of the activity jumps under the status bar when Admob's Interstitial is shown in Jetpack Compose
Here's the default example of empty activity created with Jetpack Compose, just replaced a text with a button to show fullscreen ad (Admob Interstitial)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
private var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ... load ad 

    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {
        AppTheme {
            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        interstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Show fullscreen ad"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Before pressing the button the UI looks fine (as expected):

But when I click the button to show the ad the content of app's activity jumps under the status bar:

This is very annoying. I have this issue in my real projects where I also use Jetpack Compose.
We need to use enableEdgeToEdge() or WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) to be able to draw the backround for system bars with Jetpack Compose instead of Theme/Style xml.
The issue happens with any activity which appears above app's own activity, for example:

when a dialog with app chooser appears: context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(...))

Google Play In App Review: reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo)


and so on
What is the best way to fix it?

You sould use WindowInsets.displayCutout
Like this
Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxSize()
                      .padding(innerPadding) 
.windowInsetsPadding(your'sWindowInsets.union(WindowInsets.displayCutout))
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    interstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
                }) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Show fullscreen ad"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

